# Typescript generic type

Tags: typescript, types

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
 
let myIdentity: <Input>(arg: Input) => Input = identity;
```

I understand from the code that, the 'identity' function takes an argument of generic type. I don't understand what's happening after the function. How is 'myIndentity' assignment working?

Comment: `identity` and `myIdentity` are equivalent functions, just using different syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

So, `identity` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function which, when called, must be specified with a single unconstrained *type parameter* `Type`; this function then takes a single function parameter `arg` of type `Type`, and returns a value of type `Type`:

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
    return arg;
}

//IntelliSense says this:
//function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type
```

You can get the type of `identity` by using [TypeScript's `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) (not to be confused with [JavaScript's `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)):

```
type TypeofIdentity = typeof identity
// type TypeofIdentity = <Type>(arg: Type) => Type
```

So `identity`'s type can be written as the generic [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) `<Type>(arg: Type) => Type`.

Note that `Type` is just the *name* of a type parameter and `arg` is just the *name* of an argument, and these names can be changed without changing the *type* of `identity`.  Meaning the following is completely equivalent to the version you have:

```
type TypeofIdentity = <T>(x: T) => T
```

Or this:

```
type TypeofIdentity = <Input>(arg: Input) => Input
```

---

That means your `myIdentity` variable has been [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a type completely equivalent to the type of `identity`, and you assign `identity` to `myIdentity`.  So `myIdentity` has the same value as `identity`, and you have annotated them as the same type.

You can prove this to yourself by declaring a `var` of each type; TypeScript will let you re-declare `var`s but only if the subsequent declarations are of the same type.  The fact that the following compiles means the compiler sees no important difference between the type of `identity`, the type of `myIdentity`, or `<T>(x: T)=>T`:

```
var x: typeof identity;
var x: typeof myIdentity; // okay
var x: <T>(x: T) => T; // okay
```

---

Anyway, fundamentally what you've done is made a value and then assigned that value to a new variable of the same type.  In some sense it's no different from:

```
const date = new Date(); // make a thing
let myDate: Date = date; // assign thing to another variable
```

And that means you can use `myIdentity` the same way you could use `identity`; they are the same thing, after all:

```
const str = myIdentity("str");
// const str: "str"
const tru = myIdentity(true);
// const tru: true
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/LAKFDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aACRATAptJ8BPAHgBUCAHbAPgAoBDAJwHMAuNMygSjY+zQG9QaYWgbZ4kBukZMA3KAC+oAPTKocJKgw48iQqQrV6zHoe7tDoUIUoXKycAEkd+AmgC8aG9gfbcrlWUvQzsfJxc9N08DSloZUy4PKlCrEGg6AFtsAGdyOlg+AFEAR0hEADc6ABt-ASERdQQUdCx-SNJaAA8ecxI6kBFB0XFJdE75AZElSeFVRs0WiP0SLp6eeuFvUIdnNsIPYPtwP11CCcHVQ75eHaWotA6abvZOJPZFVJr4NAyCXdOCGwiI5oORIPA4iY0CCwfBXu5kjDwQdWgCJqBKgw0M9vL5Ua4JpjsWxccdfv8CWhLsgANZ0AgYxjEh4rJ49N4kWRUoK0+mpUCwVDZb6YOjwPieaDYADuaAAImLsDROBMvj8CArxWxNRK0KLxeiQILoMK0MKsZ5yXcaAAic02lWBNDG03mth2+AMG0CoXfT2QA5WvYEGj+7COkCXF1+hiQEmx7BAA)